# Invalid parameter value on GetMyFeesEstimate

Tags: amazon-mws

I am trying to send a request to `GetMyFeesEstimate` using the Amazon MWS service ([doc](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_ES/products/Products_GetMyFeesEstimate.html)):

```
POST /Products/2011-10-01/?FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.MarketplaceId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.IdType=EAN&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.IdValue=6950029002582&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.IsAmazonFulfilled=true&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.Identifier=request1&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.ListingPrice.CurrencyCode=USD&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.ListingPrice.Amount=30.00&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.Shipping.CurrencyCode=USD&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.Shipping.Amount=3.99&FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.Points.PointsNumber=0&AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Action=GetMyFeesEstimate&MWSAuthToken=123&SellerId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2016-06-23T14:58:28Z&Version=2011-10-01&Signature=cPG3pcI0OT9b0GzkfTVPuBJ+fKo= HTTP/1.1
Host: mws.amazonservices.es
Cache-Control: no-cache

Postman-Token: 953f5ba5-d6c3-481a-5e7d-7bfa6ba2adcd
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

But I am receiving this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/">
    <Error>
        <Type>Sender</Type>
        <Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
        <Message>Invalid query string provided - FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.MarketplaceId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.IdType=EAN&amp;FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.IdValue=6950029002582&amp;FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.IsAmazonFulfilled=true&amp;FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.Identifier=request1&amp;FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.ListingPrice.CurrencyCode=USD&amp;FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.ListingPrice.Amount=30.00&amp;FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.Shipping.CurrencyCode=USD&amp;FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.Shipping.Amount=3.99&amp;FeesEstimateRequestList.FeesEstimateRequest.1.PriceToEstimateFees.Points.PointsNumber=0&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;Action=GetMyFeesEstimate&amp;MWSAuthToken=123&amp;SellerId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&amp;SignatureVersion=2&amp;Timestamp=2016-06-23T14:58:28Z&amp;Version=2011-10-01&amp;Signature=cPG3pcI0OT9a0GzkfTVPuBJ+fKo= is not valid; the value of a query string parameter may not contain a &apos;=&apos; delimiter</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestID>506e7ce6-1f5f-4e4f-afc1-e2defa175a4d</RequestID>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Comment: Not sure, but according to the documentation IdType values are: ASIN, SellerSKU. Try that instead of EAN, it might be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

As Jad said, the IdType can only be ASIN and SellerSKU, this needs to be changed.
But the exception here is the query string is invalid, as you can see in the error message. There should not be '=' in the query string. I see it in your signature, that may be the problem.